# I do not understand this Error: attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, function

This is the code I have been attempting to run with the following result -
Error: attempt to apply non-function

```
# install packages
install.packages("Ecdat")
install.packages("gapminder")
# run libraries
library(gapminder)
library(Ecdat)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

View(mtcars)

c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl,   
   y=mpg))
c + geom_col(color = blue, fill = 
  green) + 
  (main = "Car Milage Data") (xlab = 
  "Number of Cylinders") (ylab = 
  "Miles Per Gallon")
```

Comment: Do not use `c` as the name of an object since it is a function in R

Comment: The error seems to be related to `+ 
      (main = "Car Milage Data") (xlab = 
      "Number of Cylinders") (ylab = 
      "Miles Per Gallon")`

Comment: I changed the c to d but have the same error.  I removed those commands and get this: > d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y=mpg))
> d + geom_col(color = blue, fill = green)
Error in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Answer (score 2):

I noted 3 things:

- Used `c` as the name of the object, and it is one of the base R functions
- The colors inside `geom_col` need to be characters
- The way you used `main`, `xlab` and `ylab` did not have a "connector" such as `+`

I way to do your plot is

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl,y = mpg)) +
  geom_col(color = "blue", fill =  "green")+
  labs(
    x = "Number of Cylinders",
    y = "Miles Per Gallon",
    title = "Car Milage Data"
  )
```